# Run the localhost on HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to run the localhost on HTTPS instead of HTTP on windows10. Actually I want to call an API which is HTTPS and right now I am getting CORS error while calling the same.
Will the error get resolved if the application(localhost) run on https instead of http? If yes, then can anyone help me to run local host on https.

Comment: What application are you trying to serve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) as proxy-tunnel to transform your localhost from `HTTP` to a `HTTPS` URL.

For ngrok's free version, you can use the URL continuously in 24 hours. It's super easy and handy. Although the speed may has latency, for me, I think it's acceptable.

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/devops-techable/how-to-use-ngrok-as-proxy-tunnel-with-support-of-http-https-as-software-developer-e957a2139a54) for the instruction.

Comment: I am able to run local host on https using ngrok... Thank you!

Comment: That's great! I would appreciate if I had your upvote and answer marked! Thanks in advance!